# Refactoring Settings Activity

Tags: java, android

I´m having problems refactoring SettingsActivity.java.

First, I extended PreferenceActivity but it didn't take
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general) because it marks decaprecated as well as findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key). I've changed to PreferenceFragment and it took both methods above but now cannot resolve getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_settings, menu);

Furthermore it's showing: "cannot resolve symbol pref_units_keys" in
bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_units_key)));

Finally in the ForecastFragment.java I cannot get this method right:

```
private String formatHighLows(double high, double low){
         // Data is fetched in Celsius by default.
         // If user prefers to see in Fahrenheit, convert the values here.
         // We do this rather than fetching in Fahrenheit so that the user can
         // change this option without us having to re-fetch the data once
         // we start storing the values in the database
         SharedPreferences sharedPrefs =
                 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
         String unitType = sharedPrefs.getString(
                 getString(R.string.pref_units_key),
                 getString(R.string.pref_units_metric));

         if(unitType.equals(getString(R.string.pref_units_imperial))){
             high = (high * 1.8) + 32;
             low = (low * 1.8) + 32;
         }else if(!unitType.equals(R.string.pref_units_metric)){
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Unit type not found: " + unitType);
         }
```

Probably I need to declare de units and metric in the string.xml file...

What can I do??

Here is the link for the entire code: http://pastebin.com/KJRbj6Sd#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to get an Activity reference.

Try adding `getActivity()` before `getMenuInflater()`, and `getResources()` before each one of your `getString()`s.

```
private String formatHighLows(double high, double low){

     SharedPreferences sharedPrefs =
             PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
     String unitType = sharedPrefs.getString(
             getResources().getString(R.string.pref_units_key),
             getResources().getString(R.string.pref_units_metric));

     if(unitType.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_units_imperial))){
         high = (high * 1.8) + 32;
         low = (low * 1.8) + 32;
     }else if(!unitType.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_units_metric))){
         Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Unit type not found: " + unitType); }
 }
```

Comment: You mean the settings fragment? Try `getActivity().getMenuInflater()`, as said above.